# Which of these projects should I choose for summer workshop on NLP?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, machine-learning

I am planning to attend a project oriented advanced summer workshop here in India on Natural Language Processing.
Before start of the workshop, I have to make a project preference out of the following four areas about which I have limited knowledge.

> **Machine Translation** Develop an English-Indian language translation
>   system.
>
> **Parsing** Build an Indian Language (IL) Parser.
>
> **Morphological Analysis** Develop and test Morphological Analyzers for
>   Indian Languages.
>
> **Speech** Spoken Dialog Systems, Emotion/Prosody Detection, Synthesis
>   and Conversion

I have taken a course in Artificial Intelligence where NLP was introduced and fundamental sub-topics like *POS tagging(Transformation Based Learning), word prediction using N-grams, Hidden Markov Models, Viterbi Algorithm, Natural Language Parsing, Context Free Grammar, CKY Algorithm* were covered.

I understand this is a slightly vague question and the choice would depend primarily on my interests, but would appreciate guidance on which area would be better in terms of the research scope, practical application, industry opportunities etc.

EDIT: Application of skills/experience acquired while working on the project, outside NLP would also be a factor in the decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first group the four options as first three in one category-NL-Text and another fourth in other-NL-Speech, as the skill set and inclination needed to pursue those are slightly different.
So first use the criteria of do you like working in the first group or second. Once you are done with that and you choose Speech. you are done. 
But if you are on other side, now there are two categories MT and remaining MA and IL Parsing. Building a MT will focus on using the ready made components and adapt them to you language pair. If you are supposed to do it statistically, it's little more on data side and you don't gain much, I mean learn/work much as in other two.If that is rule based, there are very few making it big- but you will learn a lot. Building an IL parser is a good option and might be useful for future task where will have lot of data in IL and then text processing industry will flourish. So considering future scope in industry consider my +1. Same case is with Morphological Analysis.

Comment: Thanks Prakash, that really narrows down my choice. I don't particularly have any experience with Speech, so will avoid that. 

Regarding MA, I am conversant with only one Indian language(Hindi) for which the research center where I am interning has already built a Morphological analyser. As per my understanding you have to be fluent with a language to work on MA for it, so MA is out as well. Am I right in this deduction?

Comment: Yeah quite true.Deeper understanding of the language and it's grammar is very necessary. And Also please consider researching on the job opportunities in the market, because ultimately you are investing a Summer in it. I Wish you Best luck.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for the morphological analyzer.  Morphological analyzers are a prerequisite for doing any NLP in a language with interesting word structure, and there are lots and lots of languages out there where almost no work has been done yet. Building a good morphological analyzer for a language you know well is a reasonable summer project, so you can probably get out of the workshop having built a working, useful piece of software that other people will appreciate having.

The other areas are hotter topics these days and might look better on your CV, but they're also much more open-ended and are much harder for a relative beginner to make any real contribution in.

Comment: +1 - My experience corresponds to rmalouf's - As your summer is bounded, building a morphological analyzer allows you to get your hands dirty quickly; Its evaluation and debugging cycles will be the shortest; Plus your experience may also serve you later in other areas inside or outside NLP - automata and HMMs, both common tools for morphological analysis, are common tools for other tasks as well.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. One point I would like to clarify is that, though the summer school duration is 2 weeks, I have an option to continue working on the project even after the summer school. Moreover, as you suggested I am looking to develop experience in an area which may serve in areas inside or outside NLP.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think all of them are very actual and relevant and that it boils down to your personal interests.  I'd personally go for Speech as it seems to be the broadest of the four (relatively infinite room for improvement) so the research scope is very interesting.  If you prefer to aim for something with more concrete application, parsing and machine translation seem the way to go.

Good luck regardless of what you choose, this looks like an amazing opportunity and a great challenge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don’t know Indian. According to the sub-topics you have learnt parsing would be a better selection. However for many languages syntactic parsing is highly dependent to morphologic analysis. And unlike English many languages have complex morphologies.  Additionally neither writing a parser nor writing a morphologic analyzer from scratch is possible in three months for many languages.

So if Indian morphology is not complex go for the analyzer. It is the basic level of NLP and you will learn a lot. If it is rather hard and there are sufficient analyzers that you can use with your parsing project go for the parser.

Finally either you select the parser or analyzer, reduce your target or the project and complete it on time. For example instead of trying to write a full analyzer, try to write one that works just for inflectional suffixes.

By the way how about a stemmer?